# How Implement EasyAPNS to iOS 8?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, web-services, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use EasyAPNS on a project for iOS 8. But because the project is old and no updates for it, I'm having problems.

More specifically, with respect to the server, although it is correctly configured as the tutorial video Caixeta Raphael, presents the following problem in the log file:

> [10-Nov-2014 20:18:03 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Fatal error:  Push Badge
>   must be either Enabled or Disabled.
>
> 1) APNS::__construct -> File: apns.php (line 55)    2)
>   APNS::_registerDevice -> File: class_APNS.php (line 252)  3)
>   APNS::_triggerError -> File: class_APNS.php (line 319)
>
> in /home/pensesof/public_html/apns/classes/class_APNS.php on line 706

Someone uses, or is using EasyAPNS on current projects?

Comment: Highly recommend against using EasyAPNS given how antiquated it is. Apple has made continuous improvements to the APNS system, and php is constantly being updated as well. Have you considered using something like [PyAPNs](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs)? It's still actively being updated.

Comment: PHP is more easy for me... and this is a job, and the serve of my client  is only php / mysql. Thx

Comment: It would be worth explaining to your client the current state of EasyAPNS and that they should use the right tool for the job instead of what they decided they were going to use "just because".

Comment: There are actually several best solutions to this problem. But there are few free. My client does not want to have any kind of registration or use of servers that generate costs. Since the demand for pushs, can vary as needed. Because the app is to use a small business.

Comment: PyAPNs is open source (free) and could coexist right on the same server where you are trying to put EasyAPNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the AppDelegate.m to be used in iOS8.

First u must add the framework: AudioToolbox.framework

Go Targets> General ... scroll down at Linked Frameworks and Libraries and click on plus button, and search for AudioToolbox.framework

After copy and paste this code for your AppDelgate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AudioToolBox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    //register to receive notifications
    // Add registration for remote notifications

    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication]

    // registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    // For iOS 8:
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                      categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    // Clear application badge when app launches
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;


      return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}



#pragma mark - Configuração APNS

/*
 2
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3
 *  BEGIN APNS CODE
 4
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5
 */



/**
 8
 * Fetch and Format Device Token and Register Important Information to Remote Server
 9
 */

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {



#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR


    // Get Bundle Info for Remote Registration (handy if you have more than one app)

   // NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];

   NSString *appName = @"TesteAPNS1";

    NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];


    // Check what Notifications the user has turned on.  We registered for all three, but they may have manually disabled some or all of them.

   // NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];


    UIRemoteNotificationType rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
    // Set the defaults to disabled unless we find otherwise...

    NSString *pushBadge = @"disabled";

    NSString *pushAlert = @"disabled";

    NSString *pushSound = @"disabled";



    // Check what Registered Types are turned on. This is a bit tricky since if two are enabled, and one is off, it will return a number 2... not telling you which

    // one is actually disabled. So we are literally checking to see if rnTypes matches what is turned on, instead of by number. The "tricky" part is that the

    // single notification types will only match if they are the ONLY one enabled.  Likewise, when we are checking for a pair of notifications, it will only be

    // true if those two notifications are on.  This is why the code is written this way

    if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge){

        pushBadge = @"enabled";

    }

    else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){

        pushAlert = @"enabled";

    }

    else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound){

        pushSound = @"enabled";

    }

    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)){

        pushBadge = @"enabled";

        pushAlert = @"enabled";

    }

    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){

        pushBadge = @"enabled";

        pushSound = @"enabled";

    }

    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){

        pushAlert = @"enabled";

        pushSound = @"enabled";

    }

    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){

        pushBadge = @"enabled";

        pushAlert = @"enabled";

        pushSound = @"enabled";

    }



    // Get the users Device Model, Display Name, Unique ID, Token & Version Number

    UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    //NSString *deviceUuid = dev.uniqueIdentifier;
    NSString *deviceUuid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor ]UUIDString];// Substitui o codigo acima

    NSString *deviceName = dev.name;

    NSString *deviceModel = dev.model;

    NSString *deviceSystemVersion = dev.systemVersion;



    // Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)

    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description]

                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]

                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]

                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];



    // Build URL String for Registration

    // !!! CHANGE "www.mywebsite.com" TO YOUR WEBSITE. Leave out the http://

    // !!! SAMPLE: "secure.awesomeapp.com"

   #pragma mark - Setup Your URL here!

    NSString *host = @"www.mywebsite.com";



#pragma mark - CHANGE "/apns.php?" TO THE PATH TO WHERE apns.php IS INSTALLED

    // !!! ( MUST START WITH / AND END WITH ? ).

    // !!! SAMPLE: "/path/to/apns.php?"

    NSString *urlString = [@"/path/to/apns.php?"stringByAppendingString:@"task=register"];

    #pragma mark - Start add propertys to url

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appname="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appName];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appversion="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appVersion];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceuid="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceUuid];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicetoken="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceToken];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicename="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceName];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicemodel="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceModel];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceversion="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceSystemVersion];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushbadge="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushBadge];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushalert="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushAlert];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushsound="];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushSound];


 #pragma mark - Register the device data in server.Fire URL with data device
    // Register the Device Data

    // !!! CHANGE "http" TO "https" IF YOU ARE USING HTTPS PROTOCOL

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:host path:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSLog(@"Register URL: %@", url);

    NSLog(@"Return Data: %@", returnData);



#endif

}



/**
 113
 * Failed to Register for Remote Notifications
 114
 */

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {



#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR



    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", error);



#endif

}



/**
 125
 * Remote Notification Received while application was open.
 126
 */

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {



#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR



    NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);

    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];



    NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];

    NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);



    NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];

    NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);



    NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];

    NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];



#endif

}
@end
```

Comment: good start but slight mistake,  isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications returns a bool.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check Notifications user has turned on.
//Registered all three, but they may have manually disabled some or all of them.
NSUInteger rntypes;

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
{
    //returns UIRemoteNotificationType typedef for nsuinteger
    UIUserNotificationSettings * notificationSettings;
    notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
    rntypes = [notificationSettings types];
}
else
{
    rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
}


// Set the defaults to disabled unless we find otherwise...
NSString * pushBadge = (rntypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) ? @"enabled" : @"disabled";
NSString * pushAlert = (rntypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) ? @"enabled" : @"disabled";
NSString * pushSound = (rntypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) ? @"enabled" : @"disabled";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I ended up giving up on this code. The service is very old and outdated. So to solve I created my own APNS Server using PHP. In AppDelegate, I just started the push service.